# SEO friendly HTML5 video (video.js) intro with overlay fadeout 

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5-video, fadeout

I'm using the [video.js](http://videojs.com/) plugin and have a video intro that plays when my site loads. It works by autoplaying as soon as the page loads and it is in a div container that is z-indexed and overlayed over my home page.

I have jquery set to `delay()` and then `fadeOut()` the div out revealing my home page.

Good in theory only everyone has different connection speeds and the `fadeOut()` often happens too early or too late.

Is there a way to `fadeOut()` my div when the video has stopped?

Here is my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        $("#overlay-video").delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
   });
```

EDIT: I have also just tried the following but this also does not work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#movie-id").bind('ended', function(){
    alert("planet earth");
  });
});
```

Thanks for the replies my HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="overlay-video">
    <!-- Begin Video.js -->
    <video id="movie-id" class="video-js vjs-default-skin alignleft" width="640" height="264" poster="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.png" controls preload="auto" autoplay data-setup="{}">
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.webm" type='video/webm; codecs="vp8, vorbis"' />
        <source src="http://video-js.zencoder.com/oceans-clip.ogg" type='video/ogg; codecs="theora, vorbis"' />
    </video>
    <!-- End Video.js -->
</div>
```

My jQuery is working because I can fadeOut the video element fine.

Comment: Your second code snippet looks correct.  If you're reaching the end of the video, `ended` should fire; if it's not, maybe something else is wrong?  What if you bind `timeupdate`?  (Bind something less obnoxious than an `alert` to this, though -- I believe it should fire a lot, so a `console.log` will do nicely, if you're testing in a modern browser.)

Comment: which browsers did you test on (name, version, OS)? please also add your HTML code so we can rule out wrong ids. which jQuery version are you using? starting with 1.7 `.on()` replaces `.bind()` (which is therefore deprecated

Comment: @brettGolding, just curious if apsillers suggestions are working for you

Comment: @timpeterson, no nothing is working. I have just updated my message with the HTML I am using as well.

Comment: @jornBerkefeld I am testing on Firefox ver 12, windows 7. Using jQuery ver 1.6

Answer (score 2):

Couple things:

1. only a single `doc.ready` fxn is needed for all your scripts on your home page
2. use the `on()` method (with jQuery 1.7+)
3. **Most importantly**, `fadeOut()` needs to be inside the `on('ended')` function

As a general HTML5 `<video>` solution, this should work: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/XzCMb/1/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#movie-id").on('ended', function() {             
        console.log('im done');
        $("#overlay-video").delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
    });
});
```

However, Video-js appears to require a call to the video.js object, so do this instead: http://help.videojs.com/discussions/questions/509-videojs-and-passing-an-event-at-the-end-of-the-video

```
_V_("#movie-id").ready(function(){ //note the different selector for the ready() fxn
   this.addEvent("ended", function(){ //adding "ended" event to video-js object
     {   console.log('im done');
        $("#overlay-video").delay(10000).fadeOut('slow');
      } 
   });
 });
```

Comment: Nope no luck. I can fade the video out with fadeOut no problem. So the problem is with the .on or .blind function. Could it have something to do with my HTML? 

The fact I am using video.js wordpress plugin or that I have 3 different video sources.

Comment: @BrettGolding check out my jsfiddle it works for me: http://jsfiddle.net/trpeters1/XzCMb/1/  yeah i think it has to do the with video.js which must be somehow overriding this `on('ended')` function

Comment: @BrettGolding  check this link: http://help.videojs.com/discussions/questions/509-videojs-and-passing-an-event-at-the-end-of-the-video it specifically deals with calling the video.js object `on('ended')`. here's the code you need: `<script type="text/javascript">
_V_("example_video_1").ready(function(){
this.addEvent("ended", function(){
{window.location = "www.google.com"}
});
});
</script>`